# java FileWriter, periodically delete file contents

Tags: java, filewriter

I am using several java FileWriter to append data to an output files.  The files all remain open during processing and are periodically written to (appended to).  Occasionally, I hit a point in the logic where the contents of a currently open file needs to be deleted (the file length to become zero) and I start appending again from the top.

Without closing and reopening the file, is there an efficient method to accomplish this using FileWriter?

Answer (score 1):

> Without closing and reopening the file, is there an efficient method to accomplish this using `FileWriter`?

No. You would have use a `RandomAccessFile` with its performance and character-set issues.

Create a new `FileWriter`.

Comment: Thanks!  Close/reopen was my default method and I didn't find anything after a few searches.  Just thought I'd ask the experts too!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) instead of `FileWriter` and use `stream.getChannel().truncate(0)`. But note it's byte-oriented instead of character-oriented, so I wouldn't recommend it if `FileWriter` is a better fit.